# The Permalink doesn't work after the foreach ended

Tags: permalinks

I am facing a problem. In my homepage, i have two columns for **Latest Updates** and **Latest Promotion**. But, i have some share buttons as well. But, the permalink doesn't work for my share buttons. The permalink is still the link of **Latest Updates** after the`<?php endforeach; ?>` ended.

I use code this for **Latest Updates** on my website.

```
<?php
 $postslist = get_posts('numberposts=1&order=DESC&orderby=date');
 foreach ($postslist as $post) :
    setup_postdata($post);
 ?>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<p class="date"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></p>
<span class="button">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a>
</span>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

I use code this for **Latest Promotion** on my website.

```
<?php
$catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=2&posts_per_page=1' );
while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();
?>
<div class="kitchen-cabinet-promotion kitchen-cabinet-measure">
<h3>Monthly Promotion</h3>
<div class="banner">
<?php $img = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id)); ?>
<a href="<?php echo $img; ?>" class="shutterset_set_200"><img src="<?php echo $img; ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" /></a>
</div><!--banner-->
<div class="clear"></div>
<p class="date"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></p>
<span class="button center">
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">Read More</a>
</span>
</div><!--kitchen cabinet promotion-->
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

I use this code for **facebook share button**. I don't want to use those multi-share buttons.

```
<a href="https://facebook.com/share.php?u=<?php the_permalink() ?>" target="_blank" title="Share to FB" rel="nofollow">Share to facebook</a>
```

The actual permalink should be back to normal and get the current url since the `<?php endforeach; ?>` ended. But, it doesn't work. Any solution to fix this? I'm struggling with this.

Comment: try adding `wp_reset_query();` before calling `the_permalink`...

Comment: Which permalink do you mean?

Comment: Majick is talking about the permalink in which you have problem. after `foreach` loop add `wp_reset_postdata()`. That will be better than `wp_reset_query()`

Comment: I see. But, why does `wp_reset_postdata()` is better than `wp_reset_query()`? Can you please share it with me? So that i can learn something new. Thank you! Sumit.

Comment: `wp_reset_query` restores the globals `post` and `wp_query`. `wp_reset_postdata` just restores `post`. You only need to restore `post` after additional queries, because you didn't overwrite `wp_query`.